# CMake: conditionally generate protobuf `*pb.{h|cpp}` files when *.proto files change

Tags: c++, python, cmake, protocol-buffers

I am part of a project that is using protobufs to communicate between a Python based client and a c++ based server.  We are also using CMake.

With CMake, I am looking for a way to conditionally call the `protoc` program only when `*.proto` files change.  My current directory structure (this seems to be part of the problem) has a directory for the `*.proto` files, and separate directories for the generated `*.pb.{h|cc}` and `*_pb2.py` files:

```
  build/
  Messages/proto/  <--- .proto files are here
  Messages/cpp/    <--- would like the auto generated c++ files here
  Messages/py/     <--- would like the auto generated Python files here
  Server/Main.cpp
  Client/Main.py
  CMakeLists.txt
```

The (root) `CMakeLists.txt` file (below) runs the `protoc` program when the `build/cmake ..` command is executed:

```
project(AAA)

MESSAGE("Protobuf autogeneration STARTED")

file(GLOB proto_packages "${AAA_SOURCE_DIR}/Messages/proto/*.proto")
execute_process(COMMAND protoc -I=${AAA_SOURCE_DIR}/Messages/proto --cpp_out=${AAA_SOURCE_DIR}/Messages/cpp/ --python_out=${AAA_SOURCE_DIR}/Messages/py/ ${proto_packages})

MESSAGE("Protobuf autogeneration COMPLETED")

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
find_package(Boost)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_subdirectory(Messages/proto)
add_subdirectory(Messages/cpp)
add_subdirectory(Server)
```

The `Messages/proto/CMakeLists.txt` file (which I'm not sure has any effect):

```
file(GLOB proto_packages "${AAA_SOURCE_DIR}/Messages/proto/*.proto")
execute_process(COMMAND protoc -I=${AAA_SOURCE_DIR}/Messages/proto --cpp_out=../cpp --python_out=../py ${proto_packages}
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

**Ideally**, the `protoc` program should run as part of the `build/make` command, **and** only (re)generate the `*.pb.{h|cc}` and `*_pb2.py` files when a `*.proto` file changes.

Some files in the `Server/` directory have `#include <Messages/cpp/Xxxx.pb.h>` directives.

For bonus points, I would prefer to have the `*.pb.{h|cc}` and `*_pb2.py` files be generated into their respective directories (`Messages/cpp/` and `Messages/py/` respectively).  However, if someone is able to help with the dependency part of the problem, I am happy to have the `*.pb.{h|cc}` and `*_pb2.py` files co-exist with the `*.proto` files.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions !

Answer (score 5):

This is untested, but you need to add a custom command a custom target.

You'd need to create some variables for the output line, but without knowing how to turn *.proto into the *.pb.{h|cc} and *_pb2.py files I can't help there.  See the proto_packages_cpp and proto_packages_python variables for where those should go.

```
file(GLOB proto_packages "${AAA_SOURCE_DIR}/Messages/proto/*.proto")
add_custom_command(
    COMMAND protoc -I=${AAA_SOURCE_DIR}/Messages/proto --cpp_out=../cpp --python_out=../py ${proto_packages}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    DEPENDS ${proto_packages}
    OUTPUT ${proto_packages_cpp} ${proto_packages_python}
)
add_custom_target(protobuf_autogeneration_target ALL
    DEPENDS ${proto_packages}
)
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestions.  I will let you know if I have any success.